# QProcess Live Output Redirection

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qprocess

I'm trying to redirect the output of QProcess live into my console.
Here is the code I'm using:

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(this);
connect (process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(processOutput()));
connect (process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(processOutput()));
process->start(program);

void MainWindow::processOutput()
{
    qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput();
}
```

However the above does not redirect the output stream live into my console. The processOutput() function seems to be called every time the program tries to print something but all the output seems to be buffered by QProcess and printed on my console only after the completion of the program started by QProcess. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

I have a MessageHandler Class which redirects all qDebug messages to an Console TabOutput in my GUI App.

```
MessageHandler::handleMessages(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &cntxt, const QString &msg)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case QtDebugMsg:
        if(!m_appOutput)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Debug ::  %s\n", qPrintable(msg));
        }
        else
        {
            m_appOutput->append(msg);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

In my main.cpp, I have registered my message handler class as follows:

```
qInstallMessageHandler(MessageHandler::handleMessages);
```

The m_appOutput is a QTextEdit which is present in the MainWindow where all my app output messages are printed.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is QProcess and not the fact that qDebug needs flushing? You can check by streaming and 'endl' to the qDebug(), after reading the standard output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No difference after changing to "qDebug() << process->readAllStandardOutput() << std::endl;".

Comment: @TheDarkKnight  Actually I'm redirecting all qDebug messsages into a QTextEdit. If I print the messages directly then I'm seeing it live.  So I guess the problem has to do something with QTextEdit not flushing properly. Any help??

Comment: Please show the code for what you're actually doing.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight I have added some edits. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643293/how-does-qt5-redirect-qdebug-statements-to-the-qt-creator-2-6-console Note "On windows, qDebug() uses the debug channel, not stderr"

Comment: This may also help: http://www.qt-coding.com/2013/08/06/tip-of-the-day-redirect-qdebug-to-a-file/