# qDebug output in qtCreator while running unit tests with catch2

Tags: qt-creator, catch2

I have a project with unittests which are implemented with catch2 and using the catch2-integration in qtcreator. The unittests contain `qDebug()<<"message"` calls. The project uses CMAKE as build system. Everything compiles and I can both run the tests as standalone application and with the interface (i.e. "run selected tests") in qtcreator. Currently it is compiled in debug-mode.

However, when running in a terminal, I get all qDebug messages.
If I'm running the main application (not the unit tests), I can observe qDebug messages in the "Application output" tab.
However, if I'm running the unit tests, no matter if I use qtCreator interface or start debugging or run the compiled tests, the "Application output" stays empty.

As stated above, I'm able to see them in a terminal, but then I only can run the full test suite, while I would hope to be able only to run selected tests and get their output.

What needs to be in place that the qDebug messages which originate from catch2 unittests in qtcreator are displayed in the "Application Output" tab during test execution?

QtCreator 7.0.0, Windows, MSVC2019, 64Bit.

Amongst others I already tried (without luck): [QtCreator: qDebug Messages Not Shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41425530/qtcreator-qdebug-messages-not-shown)

Comment: I have the same problem. It looks like it's something inside Qt Creator that detects the project as being a test suite and enables the test tab. It works with Gtest and Qtest but not with catch2.